# How to organize ColdFusion-based MVC application?

Tags: model-view-controller, frameworks, coldfusion

I want to move one of our existing apps (currently located in http://www.companywebsitegoeshere.com/myapp1) to an MVC structure.

As can be seen in the URL, there are **many** apps running in the website which I intend to move at some stage. I **don't have write access** to the wwwroot (/var/www/html in my case) and the webserver is used by multiple developers across the company.

I'm hoping I can have the MVC framework core files/folders + my app all located in in 1 subfolder. In the case of myapp1, all the filers and folders will be inside /var/www/html/myapp1 subfolder.

Can you please point me to the right direction (links/guides/docs/videos/etc)? I've looked at several like cfwheels/mach-ii/fw1 but they seemed to require wwwroot access.

Comment: All of them ought to support not being in wwwroot, although all their examples often assume this. Often they assume root because then the mappings work. You often need to set this.mappings in application.cfc to get the right object paths when running in a subfolder. I've no specific experience with the frameworks listed, so I'll let others chime in on them

Comment: forgot to add that each app would have its own copy of the MVC framework core files/folders. I'm not sure if I conveyed this clearly above. and not really limiting my choices to those I mentioned. Anything is welcome as long as they are current/actively supported by the community. :)

Comment: Question still a bit vague, but I'd recommend FW/1 since it gives you the most flexibility.

Comment: I've used Model-Glue on Coldspring. Neither are required to be on wwwroot.

Comment: FW/1 doesn't need to be in the webroot - works fine with just `Application.cfc` (and an empty index.cfm) in a subdir and the rest can be anywhere else (once you have appropriate mappings/etc).

Comment: Also, FW/1 being just a single file is easy to use an individual copy per Application - just keep `framework.cfc` with the rest of your files and again reference it appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

cfwheels can live in a subdirectory just fine. as a matter of fact, i run the framework test suite from within a subdirectory off root just to make sure of this before each commit.

the only thing that you have to change when serving a website from a subdirectory is appending the url rewriting with your subdirectory path. this is a rewriter thing, not a cfwheels thing.

http://rip747.wordpress.com/2009/02/23/cfwheels-url-rewriting-in-a-subfolder/

Comment: Do I need to unzip all the contents of cfwheels.zip to my subfolder?
so I'll be having
/var/www/html/myapp1/
=> /var/html/myapp1/config/
=> /var/html/myapp1/controllers/
=> and etc
Is this correct?

Thanks Again :)